# useEffect simulating componentWillUnmount does not return updated state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a functional component that initializes a state with useState, then this state is changed via an input field.

I then have a useEffect hook simulating componentWillUnmount so that, before the component unmounts, the current, updated state is logged to the console. However, the initial state is logged instead of the current one.

Here is a simple representation of what I am trying to do (this is not my actual component):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Input = () => {
    const [text, setText] = useState('aaa');

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            console.log(text);
        }
    }, [])

    const onChange = (e) => {
        setText(e.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" value={text} onChange={onChange} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Input;
```

I initialize the state as "initial." Then I use the input field to change the state, say I type in "new text." However, when the component in unmounted, "initial" is logged to the console instead of "new text."

Why does this happen? How can I access the current updated state on unmount?

Many thanks!

Edit:

Adding text to useEffect dependency array doesn’t solve my problem because in my real-world scenario, what I want to do is to fire an asynchronous action based on the current state, and it wouldn’t be efficient to do so everytime the “text” state changes.

I’m looking for a way to get the current state only right before the component unmounts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've effectively memoized the initial state value, so when the component unmounts *that* value is what the returned function has enclosed in its scope.

[Cleaning up an effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect)

> The clean-up function runs before the component is removed from the UI
>   to prevent memory leaks. Additionally, if a component renders multiple
>   times (as they typically do), the **previous effect is cleaned up before
>   executing the next effect**. In our example, this means a new
>   subscription is created on every update. To avoid firing an effect on
>   every update, refer to the next section.

In order to get the latest state when the cleanup function is called then you need to include `text` in the dependency array so the function is updated.

[Effect hook docs](http://tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

> If you pass an empty array (`[]`), the **props and state inside the effect
>   will always have their initial values**. While passing `[]` as the second
>   argument is closer to the familiar `componentDidMount` and
>   `componentWillUnmount` mental model, there are usually better solutions
>   to avoid re-running effects too often.

This means the returned "cleanup" function still only accesses the previous render cycle's state and props.

**EDIT**

[useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

> `useRef` returns a mutable ref object whose `.current` property is
>   initialized to the passed argument (`initialValue`). The returned object
>   will persist for the full lifetime of the component.
>
> ...
>
> It’s *handy for keeping any mutable value around* similar to how you’d use instance fields in classes.

Using a ref will allow you to cache the current `text` reference that can be accessed within the cleanup function.

**/EDIT**

Component

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

const Input = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('aaa');

  // #1 ref to cache current text value
  const textRef = useRef(null);
  // #2 cache current text value
  textRef.current = text;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Mounted", text);

    // #3 access ref to get current text value in cleanup
    return () => console.log("Unmounted", text, "textRef", textRef.current);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("current text", text);
    return () => {
      console.log("previous text", text);
    }
  }, [text])

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setText(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={text} onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Input;
```

With the console.log in the returned cleanup function you'll notice upon each change in the input the previous state is logged to console.

[image: Edit zen-leftpad-twogm]

In this demo I've logged current state in the effect *and* previous state in the cleanup function. Note that the cleanup function logs first before the current log of the next render cycle.

Comment: My problem is that what I actually need to do is to dispatch an asynchronous action before the component unmounts, so in this case, I can’t use the approach you suggested because the action would be fired every time the state changed, which would be inefficient. What I’m looking for is a way to get the current state only once, right before the component is unmounted.

Comment: @edbgl Updated solution.

Comment: Thank you, Drew. I tested your solution, but the initial value is still consoled log instead of the updated one. In the console, I get "Dismounted aaa".

Comment: Ah, right, I made an error. An effect hook with empty dependency array will only ever have the initial state & props. Updating answer. What specific unmounting scenario are you trying to solve for?

Comment: @EdmundoBiglia Got a working solution, updated answer and sandbox.