# I'd like to save the React local state to redux only when leaving the page

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm using local react useState to update my inputs.
And I tried to use a clenaup function of the useEffect hook to save the state to Redux.

```
useEffect(() => {
    return function saveDetails() {
      dispatch(
        saveSiteDetails({ siteDetails, contactsToAdd, emailsToAdd, team })
      );
    };
  }, [dispatch, siteDetails, contactsToAdd, emailsToAdd, team]);
```

But the redux state is being updated every time I change the inputs. How can I achieve the functionality where the redux state updates only when users leave the current page by pressing some links inside the current page?

Comment: You could use the `dispatch` function inside a callback function used in the `onClick` property of the link.

Comment: The thing is, those links are located inside another component. That component is inside the current page. I've been thinking, should I do props drilling to pass the callback?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60734531/useeffect-simulating-componentwillunmount-does-not-return-updated-state/60734579#60734579

Comment: @KM Can you include how the components relate to each others?

Answer (score 1):

After some playing around, I think you can do this:

```js
  const _saveSiteDetails = useRef(() => {});

  _saveSiteDetails.current = () => {
    dispatch(
      saveSiteDetails({ siteDetails, contactsToAdd, emailsToAdd, team })
    );
  };

  const cleanUp = () => _saveSiteDetails.current();

  useEffect(() => cleanUp, []);
```